# Converting ArcGIS formats to ADRG data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, adrg

I have maps generated using ArcGIS (.tfw, .fig, .prj, .sbn, .shp and .dbf files).  I need to convert them to ADRG format.  Can ArcGIS do that?  If so, how?

Comment: Will just a .img work?

Answer (score 2):

ERDAS Imagine will convert to ADRG / CADRG according to this:

http://geospatial.intergraph.com/Company/News/NewsReleases/07-02-28/Leica_Geosystems_Geospatial_Imaging_Announces_New_Enhancements_and_Capabilities_for_ERDAS_IMAGINE%C2%AE_9_1.aspx

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=57&f=432&t=126794#365952

ESRI Military Analyst extension will as well according to this:

http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/defense-solutions/military-analyst-tools.html

ADRG is an ancient military special-purpose format, so queries on the topic are sparse.  One claim in forum threads is that Arc should include the means to *read* ADRG without any extensions, and another is that at one time Military Analyst wouldn't *write* to ADRG.  Nevertheless, the ESRI product page above claims the ability to render to CADRG (the compressed variant) in the present version.

**EDIT:**

Re-reading your query,"tfw, .fig, .prj, .sbn, .shp and .dbf files", it appears you may be a bit more lost than I assumed.  The above will convert a georeferenced raster (usually GRID, IMG, or Geo-Tiff) into another type of georeferenced raster, which is what I understand ADRG to be from this: http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000282.shtml

dbn, shp, and dbf files are all associated with vector [shape-files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Overview), with one row of text and numbers per shape, whether those shapes be polygon, line, or point.  Raster data is a big array of values, one per pixel, which is stretched out over a georeferenced area: a fundamentally different data model.  The .fig file escapes me at the moment.  The only thing that looks like it's associated with a raster is the .tfw file, which is used to [project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) a separate raster file (usually .tiff).

A shapefile is the bare shapes, without symbology.  Only the project file gives instructions on how it should look on screen.  If you'd like to find out how to render shapefile symbology to raster, make that a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Supported raster dataset file formats](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/supported-raster-dataset-file-formats.htm) page in the ArcGIS for Desktop Help the ARC Digitized Raster Graphics (ADRG) format that you have asked is Read-only.